# jQuery getJSON callback can't be a variable

Tags: jquery, getjson, jquery-callback

I'm trying to create a function which uses the jQuery function getJSON but I'm running in to a problem. The first part of the callback can't be variable, jQuery always interprets it as a string.

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

function getName(callbackName, callbackVal){
    $.getJSON("json_server.php",{callbackName:callbackVal}, function(result){
    //Do stuff
    });
}

getName("name", "john");

});
```

Which results in the following request URL:

```
".../json_server.php?callbackName=john" 
instead of 
".../json_server.php?name=john"
```

I already tried escaping it but that only results in errors.

What am I doing wrong, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass an object:

```
function getName(data){
    $.getJSON("json_server.php",data, function(result){
    //Do stuff
    });
}
getName({"name": "john"});
```

Or build it in the function like this:

```
function getName(callbackName, callbackVal){
    var data = {};
    data[callbackName] = callbackVal;
    $.getJSON("json_server.php",data, function(result){
    //Do stuff
    });
}
getName("name", "john");
```

Comment: Thank you very much this solved it. I'm used to PHP and this all a bit new to me.

Comment: No problem. If any of the answers to your question helped solve your problem, remember to mark them as the solution to your question by clicking the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

the problem has nothing to do with jQuery. that's how js objects works, the key can be a string or a literal, not a variable

Answer (score 0):

Construct the object in the following way

```
var x = {}
x[callbackName] = callbackVal;
$.getJSON("json_server.php",x, function(result){
    //Do stuff
    });
```

The `[]` syntax lets you define properties by name.  In this case you will assign the value of `callbackVal` to the property which is named the value of `callbackName`